# Null Error In JUnit using Spring Boot REST API Crud

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Below is my Test code where I'm getting NULL as a result.

```
public class MybatisApplicationTests {
@InjectMocks
UserController uc;
@Mock
UserService userService;

@Test
public void getUserByIdTest() {
    Long id= 6L;
    assertNotNull(uc.getUserById(id));
  }
}
```

My controller UserController.java as below,

```
 @GetMapping("/getUserById/{id}")
public User getUserById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    User user = userService.getUserById(id);
    return user;
}
```

My ServiceImpl.java for getUserById is as below,

```
@Override
public User getUserById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
     User user = userMapper.getUserById(id);
     return user;
}
```

While running above code, I'm getting below error,

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: not <null>
at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:39)
at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail(Assertions.java:109)
```

Help me to resolve the same & Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize your mock and then have to declare your mock behavior, try to change your test class like that:

```
public class MybatisApplicationTests {

@InjectMocks
UserController uc;

@Mock
UserService userService;

@Before
void setUp(){
   initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void getUserByIdTest() {
    Long id= 6L;
    User mockUser = mock(User.class);

    when(userService.getUserById(id)).thenReturn(mockUser);

    User actual = uc.getUserById(id);

    assertEquals(userMock, actual);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MybatisApplicationTests {
```

I think this is what is your solution is missing.